# ObjC: is there such a thing as a "class protocol"?

Tags: objective-c

For object instances we can have their class declare some protocol conformance as in:

```
@protocol P <NSObject>
- (void) someMethod ;
@end

@interface C : NSObject <P>
@end

@implementation C
- (void) someMethod {

}
@end
```

But what about classes?

I find myself in this situation:

```
...
Class c = [self modelClass:kind] ;
if (c) {
    model = [c performSelector: @selector(decode:) 
                    withObject: [SExpIO read: [fm contentsAtPath:target]]] ;
}
```

and I wish there were a way for me to declare that there is such a thing as protocols for class methods.

In the above example, all classes that c can be a class-instance (Hmmm??) of, declare

```
+ (id) decode: (SExp *) root ;
```

Is there a way that I could transform the above into:

```
if (c) {
    model = [c decode: [SExpIO read: [fm contentsAtPath:target]]]
}
```

by using a suitable "class protocol" declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There *are* such things as Protocols for class methods, and they're called.... Protocols. For example, it looks like you want a protocol that looks like this:

```
@protocol MyDecoder
+ (id)decode:(SExp *)root;
@end
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Class c = [self modelClass:kind];
if ([c conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyDecoder)]) {
     model = [c decode: [SExpIO read: [fm contentsAtPath:target]]];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A protocol is just a list of method declarations. They can be class methods or instance methods.  Example:

```
@protocol MyProtocol

+ (id) aClassMethod;
+ (void) someOtherClassMethod;
- (void) someInstanceMethod;

@end
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that... neat.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect that! Thanks!! I tried and it even compiles, but I'm puzzled: given that
Class c = [self modelClass:kind] ;
really is a roundabout way of saying
Class c = NSClassFromString(@"SomeClassThatIndeedImplementsModel") ;
how come that this compiles at all:
if (c) {
    model = [c decode: [SExpIO read: [fm contentsAtPath:target]]] ;
}
"Class" by itself doesn't have any type information, it seems?

Comment: Classes are objects in Objective-C. Classes have meta-classes, which are also objects: `typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
`

Comment: +1 Annoying that the Apple "The Objective-C Programming Language" reference doesn't mention this anywhere, nor does it include a single class method in its many code snippets