# Adding protocols for dynamically created UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, uipickerview

This question relates to this [SO question (*please see accepted answer*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068434/obj-c-can-a-class-object-conform-to-a-protocol). I'm adding a *UIPickerView* to a view which has not added the *UIPickerViewDelegate* or *UIPickerViewDataSource* protocols in its interface. However, all the required methods for the *UIPickerView* object has been properly implemented, and the program runs fine with these delegates:

```
pv.delegate = self;
pv.dataSource = self;
```

Since the protocols are not added in the class interface, Xcode throws these two warnings accordingly:

```
Assigning to 'id<UIPickerViewDelegate>' from incompatible type
Assigning to 'id<UIPickerViewDataSource>' from incompatible type
```

This code seems to add the required protocols, and the warnings stop as soon as the picker view delegate and datasource properties are assigned the newly created *delegateClass*.

```
UIPickerView *pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

Class<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> delegatedClass = (Class<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>)[self class];

pv.delegate = delegatedClass;
pv.dataSource = delegatedClass;
```

However, even with no errors, the program crashes.

Is the implementation or assignment wrong, perhaps?

**UPDATE:** *screenshot of the error*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a class as delegate. Do set an instance to resolve this issue.

```
UIPickerView *pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
pv.delegate = self;
```

instead of

```
UIPickerView *pv = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

Class<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> delegatedClass = (Class<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>)[self class];

pv.delegate = delegatedClass;
```

While defining your custom delegate protocol use only

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
```

instead of

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<YOUR_PROTOCOL> delegate;
```

Comment: Properties are usually set in the headers, aren't they? How and where should this be declared for dynamic implementation?

Comment: can you add a screenshot

Comment: Sorry; a screenshot of?

Comment: Screen shot of ur error . As you mentioned its compilation issue

Comment: its not a compile time error image shows the runtime issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78887/discussion-between-idev-and-isofia).